# Can't compile a new module in ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I am trying to compile a new module for ejabberd in erlang.I am following this tutorial:http://jasonrowe.com/2011/12/30/ejabberd-offline-messages

I am trying to compile this code:

```
%% name of module must match file name
-module(mod_http_offline).

-author("Earl The Squirrel").

%% Every ejabberd module implements the gen_mod behavior
%% The gen_mod behavior requires two functions: start/2 and stop/1
-behaviour(gen_mod).

%% public methods for this module
-export([start/2, stop/1, create_message/3]).

%% included for writing to ejabberd log file
-include("ejabberd.hrl").

%% ejabberd functions for JID manipulation called jlib.
-include("jlib.hrl").

start(_Host, _Opt) ->
        post_offline_message("testFrom", "testTo", "testBody"),
        ?INFO_MSG("mod_http_offline loading", []),
        ejabberd_hooks:add(offline_message_hook, _Host, ?MODULE, create_message, 50).  



stop (_Host) ->
        ?INFO_MSG("stopping mod_http_offline", []),
        ejabberd_hooks:delete(offline_message_hook, _Host, ?MODULE, create_message, 50).



create_message(_From, _To, Packet) ->
        Type = xml:get_tag_attr_s("type", Packet),
        FromS = xml:get_tag_attr_s("from", Packet),
        ToS = xml:get_tag_attr_s("to", Packet),
        Body = xml:get_path_s(Packet, [{elem, "body"}, cdata]),
        if (Type == "chat") ->
            post_offline_message(FromS, ToS, Body)
        end.



post_offline_message(From, To, Body) ->
        ?INFO_MSG("Posting From ~p To ~p Body ~p~n",[From, To, Body]),
        ?INFO_MSG("post request sent (not really yet)", []).
```

I have added jlib.hrl,ejabberd.hrl to my folder.But when I try to compile this code I am getting following errors:

```
jlib.hrl:22: can't find include lib "p1_xml/include/xml.hrl"
mod_http_offline.erl:21: undefined macro 'INFO_MSG/2'
mod_http_offline.erl:27: undefined macro 'INFO_MSG/2'
mod_http_offline.erl:44: undefined macro 'INFO_MSG/2'
jlib.hrl:426: record xmlel undefined
jlib.hrl:466: type xmlel() undefined
mod_http_offline.erl:11: function start/2 undefined
mod_http_offline.erl:11: function stop/1 undefined
mod_http_offline.erl:38: function post_offline_message/3 undefined
mod_http_offline.erl:8: Warning: behaviour gen_mod undefined
```

How can I resolve this ?

My Ejabberd version:2.1.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jlib.hrl file in ejabberd repository contains `-include("ns.hrl").` (line 21) and `-include_lib("p1_xml/include/xml.hrl").` line 22. The include_lib means that it will search the file in library path. You could modify this and add the necessary files in your directory (maybe a simple solution to test?) but I think that the clean way is to add tour file to the ejabberd application and use rebar to compile it.

Comment: How can I run rebar ? I couldn't find the location of rebar in ubuntu.

Comment: If you clone ejabberd from github [https://github.com/processone/ejabberd], it will come with rebar and all the application structure + installation instructions

Comment: I already installed ejabberd.But I don't know how to run rebar.

Comment: :o) I didn't install ejabberd, but generally you simply have to type ./rebar compile or other command. documentation at [https://github.com/rebar/rebar/wiki]

Comment: I think I have to know ejabberd files location.Do you know where is the ejabberd files ? Because when I download the source I see rebar file in directory.But I don't know these files locations in ubuntu.

Comment: ejabberd looks to be a standard OTP application. the .erl files are in the src directory, the .hrl in the include directory and the .beam in the ebin directory (after compilation). You will first have to load the dependencies (./rebar get-deps).

Comment: Not I mean where is the rebar file location ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67548/discussion-between-pascal-and-okan).